# Concatenation operator in VHDL: Comparing element of an array and making a vector

Tags: vhdl

What I am trying to do is as follows:
I am taking few elements of an array, comparing them with a fixed value and trying to create a vector out of it.

Here is a piece of code:

```
architecture behav of main_ent is
... 
type f_array is array(0 to 8) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal ins_f_array: f_array;
signal sel_sig_cmd : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); 
...
process begin
sel_sig_cmd <= ((ins_f_array(4) = x"3A")&(ins_f_array(3)= x"3A")&(ins_f_array(2)= x"3A")&(ins_f_array(1)= x"3A"));

....
end process;
...
```

This should give something like **sel_sig_cmd = 1000** or may be **1011 etc**. But this is not working. Is there any alternative to this code?
 cheers 
 Tahir

Comment: "But this is not working" isn't a specific problem (an essential part of a [mcve], see the last heading **Verifiable**).  You should be producing an analysis error to the effect there is no visible function `&`. An MCVe helps future readers replicate a specific problem and demonstrate the solution.

Comment: Not working means this is not correct, as experienced guys might be knowing it already. This will not compile and error is, I think, already clear for experienced people(even I can see it, but can't resolve it). That's why I wrote something I wanted to achieve from this code.

Comment: So I resolve to make a function in end, that took Boolean(the comparison with = operator) and returned std_logic.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the = function in VHDL returns a boolean, not a std_logic.
In VHDL '93, there is no tidy way to do this, other than set each bit manually:

```
sel_sig_cmd(3) <= '1' when (ins_f_array(4) = x"3A") else '0'
sel_sig_cmd(2) <= '1' when (ins_f_array(3) = x"3A") else '0'
-- etc
```

but in VHDL 2008, there are the relational operators (?= ?/= etc), that return std_logic on compare. So your code becomes:

```
sel_sig_cmd <= (   (ins_f_array(4) ?= x"3A")
                 & (ins_f_array(3) ?= x"3A")
                 & (ins_f_array(2) ?= x"3A")
                 & (ins_f_array(1) ?= x"3A") );
```

Comment: On a side note, these operators are broken in older versions of Vivado, if you're a Xilinx user. You need 2017.4 or newer for them to actually work!

Comment: A couple of -1993 compatible ways come to mind. An added conversion function `function to_stdulogic (inp: boolean) return std_ulogic is begin if inp = TRUE then  return '1'; else return '0'; end if;  end function;` and `sel_sig_cmd <= ( to_stdulogic (ins_f_array(4) = x"3A") &  to_stdulogic (ins_f_array(3) = x"3A") & to_stdulogic (ins_f_array(2) = x"3A") & to_stdulogic (ins_f_array(1) = x"3A") );` OR just use a loop statement in the process `for i in 4 downto 1 loop if ins_f_array (i) = x"3A" then sel_sig_cmd(i - 1) <= '1'; else sel_sig_cmd(i - 1) <= '0'; end if; end loop;`

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Tricky is a good one to follow. However, if you want to implement it in a process, then the process can be rewritten as follows :

```
architecture behav of main_ent is
... 
type f_array is array(0 to 8) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal ins_f_array: f_array;
signal sel_sig_cmd : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); 
...
process(ins_f_array(4 downto 1)) begin
if ((ins_f_array(4) = x"3A")&(ins_f_array(3)= x"3A")&
              (ins_f_array(2)= x"3A")&(ins_f_array(1)= x"3A")) then
sel_sig_cmd <= "XXXX" -- Enter your desired value
....
end process;
...
```

This process would be tedious though as it has to cover all the 16 possibilities of the "if condition".

Another implementation is to use an if condition for each bit as follows :

```
architecture behav of main_ent is
... 
type f_array is array(0 to 8) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal ins_f_array: f_array;
signal sel_sig_cmd : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); 
...
process(ins_f_array(4 downto 1)) begin
if (ins_f_array(4) = x"3A") then
sel_sig_cmd(3) <= "X" -- Enter your desired value
else
sel_sig_cmd(3) <= "X" -- Enter your desired value
end if;
-- Repeat for other bits
....
end process;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the "=" operator  :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity tb is
end entity;

architecture behav of tb is

  function "=" (Left, Right: std_logic_vector) return std_logic is
  begin
    if (Left = Right) then
      return '1';
    else
      return '0';
    end if;
  end function "=";


  type f_array is array(0 to 8) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  signal ins_f_array: f_array := (x"00",x"01",x"02",x"03",x"04",x"05",x"06",x"07",x"08");
  signal sel_sig_cmd : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); 

  begin

    process (ins_f_array(1 to 4)) begin
      sel_sig_cmd <= ((ins_f_array(4) = x"3A")&(ins_f_array(3) = x"3A")&(ins_f_array(2) = x"3A")&(ins_f_array(1) = x"3A"));
    end process;

    process
    begin
      wait for 10 us;
      for i in 0 to 8 loop  
        ins_f_array(i) <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(ins_f_array(i)) + 1);
      end loop;
    end process;

end architecture;
```